# Namespaced model in Rails generating NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I have a folder structure like this:

```
app/
  models/
    bar/
      foo.rb
      connection.rb
    foo.rb
```

`connection.rb` is an "abstract class" for connecting to another database, so:

```
class Bar::Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "outsidedb_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

`bar/foo.rb` is for accessing the `foos` table from `outsidedb`, so:

```
class Bar::Foo < Bar::Connection
end
```

And `foo.rb` is for accessing the `foos` table from the app's db, so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

From the rails console if I do `Foo.first` or `Bar::Foo.first` things behave as a I would expect in that I get the first entry from the `foos` table of the app db and the external db, respectively.

However, if I try to access `Foo` from within `bar/foo.rb` I get the following:

```
class Bar::Foo < Bar::Connection
  def self.test
      Bar::Foo.first #=> works
      Foo.first      #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Bar::Foo::Foo
  end

  def self.other_test
    Foo.parent                    #=> Object
    Foo.superclass                #=> ActiveRecord::Base
    Object::Foo.first             #=> works
    ActiveRecord::Base::Foo.first #=> works, but with "warning: toplevel constant 
                                  #   Foo referenced by ActiveRecord::Base::Foo
  end
end
```

I can obviously get things working, but I'm looking for a sounder understanding of what's going on. I'm assuming I'm missing something between Ruby's constant/class evaluation and Rail's builtin auto-loading...

1. What is `.parent` returning (not the 'parent' class)?
2. Why do I get the error in `.test`, but I don't get it in the rails console?
3. Why does `Object::Foo` seem to work? Is it the right thing to do?
4. Why does `ActiveRecord::Base::Foo` work, but with a warning?
5. There a more rails way to do what I've done without just renaming one of my `foo.rb` classes?

I'm on `Rails '3.2.13'` and `Ruby 1.9.3-p194`, just so you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be fixed with

```
::Foo.first
```

Here `::Foo` indicating the class `Foo` in top namespace.

You problem comes from the fact, that there is another `Foo` class in the namespace (`Bar`) you are working in. So you should be explicit.

As to the question why `Object::Foo` works (with warnings), it's a (less) known behaviour of name lookup in Ruby. Please see [this](http://makandracards.com/makandra/20633-ruby-constant-lookup-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly) article for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was causing a problem, hence the shot in the dark with `Object::Foo`. Is there a difference between `Object::Foo` and `::Foo`? I mean, they evaluate to the same thing, but so does `ActiveRecord::Base::Foo` and that throws a warning so I figure there could be.

Comment: @GrayKemmey it's interesting question, I wold recommend to see this article http://makandracards.com/makandra/20633-ruby-constant-lookup-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

Answer (score 1):

Here's some documentation about the `.parent` method that should help answer your first question: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-module-parents. Scroll down to Section 3.3 for the relevant part.

The `.parent` method comes with Active Support which provides Ruby extensions to Ruby on Rails components. The `.parent` method is an extension for Modules and it returns the name of the module that contains the current class. So, if you did `Bar::Foo.parent`, the return value should be `Bar`.

However, when the class doesn't have an enclosing module, the return value will default to `Object`. This is what's happening when you do `Foo.parent` since `Foo` here refers to the `Foo` class that is not in the `Bar` namespace.

Relevant Rails magic: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c9bbac46ddfc68caff6cd8a95c8d0fd045bd9201/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb