# Namespaced class references inside other classes generate uninitialized constant errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

in my Rails app I'm making liberal use of class namespacing like so:

```
class Person
  class PrimaryEmailAddress
    class Update < Trailblazer::Operation

      def persist(options, **)
        Shared::Property::HasOne::Update.(
          {property_class: PrimaryEmailAddress, property_value: @params[:email_address]},
          'current_user' => self['current_user'], parent_node: options[:person])
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the ruby interpreter keeps thinking that my namespaced, embedded functions are part of other class' namespace, and it throws `uninitialized constant` errors. i.e. at runtime I get an error like this

```
uninitialized constant Person::Shared::Property
```

Basically, the interpreter is looking at this function `Shared::Property::HasOne::Update` and treating it like it's in the `Person` namespace, when it's not, and then throwing an error.

I can get around the problem by explicitely stating that the function is in the `Object` namespace, like so `Object::Shared::Property::HasOne::Update`, but adding `Object::` all over the place is annoying and ugly. Is there a better solution anyone knows of? Short of rewriting all of my class names / namespacing.

I imagine part of the problem is that `Person::Shared` is a valid namespace, and so the ruby interpreter starts treating the `Shared::Property:: ...` reference like I just forgot to add `Person` to the beginning.

I really appreciate any feedback!!

Comment: Try adding `::Shared...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853661/namespaced-model-in-rails-generating-nameerror-uninitialized-constant?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Namespaced model in Rails generating NameError: uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853661/namespaced-model-in-rails-generating-nameerror-uninitialized-constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: by adding `::` in front of a class reference, I force the ruby interpreter to look at the top level namespace. i.e. instead of `Object::Shared::Property::HasOne::Update` I can do `::Shared::Property::HasOne::Update`, which I find more readable.

While there are a fair number of questions about uninitialized constant problems, I had trouble finding this answer because all the questions I found were framed in specific cases, rather then being genericized. It seems *likely* that this is a duplicate question and I just haven't found the other one, but I'm going to post this QA here in case I'm wrong and this helps someone else running into this same problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255150/how-to-solve-the-object-doesnt-support-inspect-error/10255357) ended up leading me to the correct answer.